# How to start ReactNative on Android?

Tags: react-native

I had installed `Node.js`、`python 2.7.13`、`git for windows`、`C++` , and i used cmd : `npm install -g react-native-cli`、`react-native init MyProject` creat a ReactNative project .

I see the information `To run your app on Android`
[image]

Finally i use cmd: `react-native run-androi`d on my project root.

And i open my android studio like this:
[image]

My question is what is next step ?

How do i compile the project ?

Is my step correct for now ?

Any help would be grated appreciated , thanks in advance.

I take the advice and try to run app , i use second cmd:`react-native run-android`
It shows SDK locations not found:
[image]

Should i change my SDK location ?

Comment: thats it  connect a device or emulator, run adb devices make sure your device is listed and run react-native run-android in project root.

Comment: How do i run my adb devices ?  My run button gui is invisible on this project.

Comment: go to your android studio sdk manager and see if sdk packages n tools are installed properly

Comment: Is it must be `Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1` ?  If i just see that 23.2.1 had installed .  Do you know what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Open your **android** folder

2) Create **local.properties** file

3) Edit file **sdk.dir = {sdk location}** eg: sdk.dir = /Users/(name)/Library/Android/sdk

4) run application again, `react-native run-android`

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, it has been a long time that i have known how to run the project on android, your answer is what i do it now. Thank you.

Comment: I know its too late, but it may be useful others who are beginner in react native :)